# Submit UITextField when bluetooth barcode scanner adds a Carriage Return to input in Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, barcode, carriage-return

We are building an iOS app in Swift4 that allows a user to connect a bluetooth barcode scanner (acts as normal keyboard), to scan data into a UITextField.  I am trying to get a process to run when the carriage return is added at the end of the scanned data by the scanner.  That process sends the data to an api endpoint that then saves the data to the appropriate database.

Scanning into the UITextField works fine, but it will not submit unless we check the string length and submit based on that.  Unfortunately, that is a terrible way to process this since too few or too many characters will throw off subsequent scans, leaving me with a whole series of bad data.

Current  Code:

```
@IBAction func textFieldEditingChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
    if(sender.text!.count >= 12){
        if(sender.text!.count == 12){
            textView.text = textView.text + "\n" + sender.text!

            let  token = (SessionManager.shared.credentials?.accessToken)
            let email = SessionManager.shared.profile?.email ?? "none"
            let bearerString = "Bearer " + token!
            let headers = [
                BEARER TOKEN INFO
            ]
            let date = Date()
            let ERecord = ARecord(scannedId: sender.text!, scanDateTime: dateFormatter.string(from: date), deviceId: UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString, scannerUser: userCurrent.userID)

            eventAttendanceRecord.append(eventRecord)

            let parameters = [
                "scannedId": sender.text!,
                "scanDateTime": dateFormatter.string(from: date),
                "deviceId": UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString,
                "scannerUser": userCurrent.userID
                ] as [String : Any]

            let postData =  try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])

            let baseUrl = API ENDPOINT

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: baseUrl)! as URL,
                                              cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                              timeoutInterval: 10.0)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
            do{
                let encodedData = try JSONEncoder().encode(eventRecord)
                request.httpBody = encodedData
            }
            catch{
                print("error happened here")
            }


            let session = URLSession.shared
            let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                if (error != nil) {
                    print(error)
                } else {
                    let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
                    print(httpResponse)
                }
            })

            dataTask.resume()

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.makeFile()
            }
        }
        sender.text = ""
        sender.text?.removeAll()
    }
}
```

I have tried to clear the text field after processing, but if for example a short ID number is scanned it will not submit since it is fewer the 12 characters.  However, the next scan will add it's data and the form will submit prematurely (scan 1 + first X digits of second scan).  I have tried adding:

```
        sender.text = ""
        sender.text?.removeAll()
```

...but since the keyboard, in this case the bluetooth hand scanner, continues typing the last of the few characters from its scan, then the UITextField is left with a couple of digits and the bad numbers continue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to look at some of the other delegate methods for the UITextField. Here's some code I wrote for another application. See if any of this helps. The trick, I think, are ending edit mode when you detect the return, using a call like this:
`searchTextField.endEditing(true)`

```
extension WeatherViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        searchTextField.endEditing(true)
        print(searchTextField.text!)
        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        // use searchTextField.text to get the weather, then...
        if let city = searchTextField.text {
            weatherManager.fetchWeather(cityName: city)
        }
        searchTextField.text = ""
    }

    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField.text != "" {
            return true
        } else {
            textField.placeholder = "Enter a city"
            return false
        }
    }
}
```